# PHP Echo Order Behaviour

Tags: php, echo, yahoo-api

I have a PHP script that requires the Yahoo SDK.  When I include the following I get no echo output until the script completes:

require("/root/yahoosdk/ysdk/examples/common.inc.php");

I can comment that line and I see all echo's occurring for each iteration as and when they should.

Everything works ok however the output must be getting held in RAM until the script is complete, im iterating thousands of posts so this could become problemtic.

Driving me nuts! Any help is appreciated!

Sam

Comment: If I remember correctly PHP echoed data in chunks when they reached a certain size. You may try to fiddle with flush() and see if it does anything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code in /root/yahoosdk/ysdk/examples/common.inc.php

Make sure it is not enabling output buffering whiuch would prevent any output until script completion.

See [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: Bang on, ob_start('mb_output_handler'); was set.

Thankyou so much! :))